# How xVA is applied to determine final price

Tags: valuation, cva

Typically, the Actual price is derivative transaction (e.g. Swap) is sum of Base price and xVA e.g. cVA.

Where Base price is analytical price with consideration of standard parameters e.g. risk free rate for discounting future cash flows.

For simplicity, lets assume only valuation adjustment is considered as cVA, and typically it is negative.

Therefore if a Bank is transacting such derivative contract with a low rated counterparty without any collateral consideration (e.g. end user), typically cVA will be Negative.

So given that Actual price = Base price + cVA, and cVA is negative, does it mean that Bank is offering this derivative in cheaper price?

I felt this is counter-intuitive, and such transaction should be costlier.

Is there something I am missing terribly in xVA understanding.

Any intuitive explanation will be very helpful.

Comment: If you buy a derivative and your counterparty (bank) defaults, would you prefer the price you paid to have been cheaper or more expensive when you entered it? See for example [risk.net](https://www.risk.net/definition/credit-valuation-adjustment-cva).

Comment: I see. So here the Actual price is from Buyer pov. Is there any possibility to see how an invoice looks like with such `cVA` (or `xVA`) adjustment from buyer as well as seller poc?